# Extracting elements from a custom list

Tags: c#

I have a class packetHandler and within that I have a class DataBuffer

```
public class DataBuffer
{
    public int nextsetind;
    public int ID;
    public int format;
    public byte[] bufs;
    //public Double[] bufs;
    //public int[] bufs;
    public DataBuffer() { }
}
```

I then have a custom list using DataBuffer

```
public List<DataBuffer> dataResult = new List<DataBuffer>();
```

The byte[] bufs contains raw data so could be anything, int, double, string etc. 
I have a method which populates this list and passes the list to another method.

```
dat.nextsetind = nextsetind;
dat.ID = ID;
dat.format = format;
dat.bufs = b;
this.dataResult.Add(dat);
si_DataReceived(dataResult);
```

Could anyone tell me how to extract the byte[] bufs (everything else is a preamble) from this list so that I can convert it in order to be displayed in a graph & rich text box?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to extract just the `bufs` field into its own collection you could use this:

```
var bufsCollection = dataResult.Select(x => x.bufs); // bufsCollection will be an IEnumerable<byte[]>
var bufsCollection = dataResult.Select(x => x.bufs).ToList(); // bufsCollection will be an List<byte[]>
```

Comment: Make sure if you choose this option you include the `System.Linq` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

As buff could be anything I suggest you to keep type as well in DataBuffer or as Generic. So that you can Cast from [Enumerable.Cast(TResult)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb341406(v=vs.100).aspx])